# How do I use media queries to make divs show/disappear depending on height/width of screen?

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design

I have two divs with IDs `#div1` and `#div2`.

I want to:

- show #div1 if `width >= 900px OR height >= 500px`
- show #div2 otherwise, i.e. `width < 900px OR height < 500px`

How can I achieve this with media queries?

I have tried the following, but it is not working:

```
@media (max-width: 900px), (max-height: 500px) {
  #div1 {
    display: block !important;
  }

  #div2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 901px), (min-height: 501px) {
  #div1 {
    display: none !important;
  }

  #div2 {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to specify both queries. Just pick which one is the default and put that one outside a media query (usually if you are designing for a phone, you would have that one as the default)

Answer (score 1):

It is because it is the other way arround:

`width >= 900px` translate to `min-width: 900px`

`height >= 500px` translate to `min-height: 500px`

`width < 900px` translate to `max-width: 899px`

`height < 500px` translate to `max-height: 499px`

As mention in the comment in your case you don't need 2 media queries

```css
#div1 {
  display: none !important;
}

#div2 {
  display: block !important;
}


@media (min-width: 900px), (min-height: 500px) {
  #div1 {
    display: block !important;
  }

  #div2 {
    display: none !important;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one inside a media query

```
#div1 {
  display: none !important;
}

#div2 {
  display: block !important;
}

@media (min-width: 900px or min-height: 500px) {
  #div1 {
    display: block !important;
  }

  #div2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

}

You also don't do an OR that way. see my changes above.

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
    display: block !important;
 }

#div2 {
    display: none !important;
 } 

@media (max-width: 900px), (max-height: 500px) {
    #div1 {
        display: none !important;
     }
    #div2 {
        display: block !important;
     }
 }
```